# No module named 'requests' Error in while running python script in Azure Function App

Tags: python, python-requests, azure-functions

I have created a python project in VS Code and deployed it on Azure Function with all the required file like requirements.txt.
Code is running successfully on my local machine but giving error when I am running it on Azure Function as "No module named 'requests'".
My requirements.txt file consist of following elements:

azure-functions
requests
PyJWT
cryptography

So Is  there any way to manually install this package on Azure Functions Linux VM. I am using consumption plan of Azure functions

Comment: Have you pip installed your requirements.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Code is running successfully on my local machine but giving error when I am running it on Azure Function as "No module named 'requests'".

Your `function` can run successfully locally, indicating that `requests` has been installed.

You can try to use this command to generate your `requirements.txt` in case the `requirements.txt` created by yourself is wrong:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

[image]

Then you can try to redeploy, if it is not successful, you can try to deploy your `function` using this command:

```
func azure functionapp publish <function app name> --build remote
```

`<function app name>` is the name of your `Azure Function App` in your `Azure Portal`.