# Azure Function working when being deployed via VS Code, but fails via DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions

I have an Azure function, which works properly when being executed locally and works in the cloud as well when being deployed via VS Code.
When I create a release in Devops though, it gives me following error:

```
Result: Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'.
```

which is weird, as the requests library is part of the requirements.txt. I tried additionally to add a command line step, which will install this libray:

```
steps:
- script: |
   pip install azure-functions
   python -m pip install requests
  displayName: 'Install required libraries'
```

but it gives me the same error when I deploy the function.
My Azure Function deployment looks as following:

```
steps:
- task: AzureFunctionApp@1
  displayName: 'Azure Function App Deploy: int'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'my_subsc'
    appType: functionAppLinux
    appName: 'int'
```

Is there something I should add to this step?

Comment: You could check this. Almost identical case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67355038/no-module-named-requests-error-in-while-running-python-script-in-azure-functio

Comment: this is a different issue, as for me it is working when I deploy it via VS Code. Only via Azure DevOps it is not working, which means that there is something wrong with the agent and the libraries

Comment: yeah you can change the agents, like ubuntu windows VS latest etc

Comment: hey @Cait did you manage to solve this at the end?

Comment: @DanielWeigel sorry for the late reply, yes I added the library to my requirements.txt and installed it from there. I added this step to my pipeline: pip install --target="$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_olga_repo/af_drop/.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_olga_repo/af_drop/requirements.txt